# Integrate IMCache with web application

Tags: caching, guava

I am trying to integrate IMCache offheap with web application. When I ran the samples given(Added the code below), JVM never exits after successfully executing the code.

```
    OffHeapByteBufferStore bufferStore = new OffHeapByteBufferStore(8388608 ,10, 1);
    final Cache<String,String> offHeapCache = CacheBuilder.offHeapCache().storage(bufferStore)
      .cacheLoader(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
        public String load(String key) {
            return cacheDao.load(key);
        }
    }).evictionListener(new EvictionListener<String, String>() {
        public void onEviction(String key, String value) {
            cacheDao.store(key, value);
        }
    }).build();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        offHeapCache.put("key-" + i, "value - " + i);
    }  
    System.out.println(offHeapCache.get("key-" + 100));
```

How can I integrate offheap cache with my web application?

Comment: @yusufaytas Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: Sounds like threads are created in user mode, but should be daemons. There might be a `shutdown()` method you have to call.

Comment: Thanks @BenManes . I never see any shutdown() methods in it. But the other examples run and exit JVM once it is complete.

Comment: You might want to open a github issue. I see some threads created [here](https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache/blob/master/imcache-offheap/src/main/java/com/cetsoft/imcache/cache/offheap/OffHeapCache.java#L140) that might be the cause of your problem by not be daemons.

Comment: Fixed the issue related to demonization of the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imcache uses an executor service to clean up the byte buffers. This is actually nearly same as garbage collection.

You can check the source code at https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache/blob/master/imcache-offheap/src/main/java/com/cetsoft/imcache/cache/offheap/OffHeapCache.java#L145

Comment: Shouldn't they be daemon threads to allow for a graceful shutdown? I think that's all @jaghan is requesting.

Comment: I think, it makes sense to deamonize them. @Ben Manes would you be interested in creating an issue related to deamonization.